# Simple 3 line applescript - Error -128

Tags: macos, applescript

I have a scenario where I'd like 2 separate applescripts.

The idea is super simple. 2 Applications, but only one runs at a time.

Example: Close application 1, launch application 2 (and vise versa)

Here are the 2 scripts I have:

A.) OpenSteam

```
tell application "Plex Home Theater" to quit
delay 5
tell application "Steam" to activate
```

B.) OpenPlex:

```
tell application "Steam" to quit
delay 5
tell application "Plex Home Theater" to activate
```

The script "OpenSteam" works perfectly fine. It does exactly what I want it to do. However, the same script in reverse (OpenPlex) does not seem to work.

Steam closes, but my script then gives me the following error *Note, Plex is not launched:

```
error "Steam got an error: User canceled." number -128
```

I have no idea what this means, and was hoping someone could help me out.

--

I got my initial information from here: https://forums.plex.tv/index.php/topic/27945-harmony-one-custom-command/#entry179765 I have revised the example scripts to fit my needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your headache lays with how Steam handles its exit status. Steam probably doesn't have applescript integration, so it considers a `quit` command from applescript an unclean exit. It would still quit, but it will let you know about it. What you need is a way to ignore the error message and execute the rest of the script nevertheless.

```
try
    tell application "Steam" to quit
    on error error_message number error_number
        if error_number is equal to -128 then
        --Keep Calm and Carry On
        else
            display dialog error_message
        end if
end try
delay 5
tell application "Plex Home Theater" to activate
```

You can combine the two scripts into one toggle/switch:

```
set steamRunning to false
set plexRunning to false

try
    do shell script "pgrep -l -f 'Steam.app'"
    set steamRunning to true
end try

try
    do shell script "pgrep -l -f 'Plex Home Theater'"
    set plexRunning to true
end try

if steamRunning is true and plexRunning is false then

    try
        tell application "Steam" to quit
    on error error_message number error_number
        if error_number is equal to 128 then
            --Keep Calm and Carry On
        else
            display dialog error_message
        end if
    end try
    delay 5
    tell application "Plex Home Theater" to activate

end if


if steamRunning is false and plexRunning is true then

    tell application "Plex Home Theater" to quit
    delay 5
    tell application "Steam" to activate

end if
```

I don't have either app so I cannot debug. There could be multiple processes named "steam", given its game-thing, so I used "Steam.app", assuming that's the app name under `/Applications/`.

Comment: Wow, thanks for these suggestions. When I get a chance I will test this out and see how it goes.

Comment: So, I had to make it " if error_number is equal to -128 then", otherwise, the script would halt and give me a "display dialog error_message". Otherwise the script seems to work great now! I have to keep the scripts separate, because when I add them to my Harmony Remote, they will be separate tasks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried...

```
launch application "Plex Home Theater"
```

Comment: tell application "Plex Home Theater" to activate does work, if I re-run the script "OpenPlex", after Steam has been closed, then Plex will open. The script is halting upon closing Steam, which is the issue.